# SetVisible(Boolean) is undefined in Java. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, swing

**So basically this is a grade calculator program. And I want to switch to the schedule program by triggering the button. But eclipse underlines setVisible(true) and says that it is undefined. So please help. =]**

================================================================================================

Main program

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class welcomescreen extends JFrame {

    public welcomescreen() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        createMenuBar();

        setTitle("Welcome");
        setSize(551, 571);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("My Schedule");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
                myschedule s = new myschedule();
                s.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 15));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 452, 123, 57);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JTextArea txtrWelcomeToGrade = new JTextArea();
        txtrWelcomeToGrade.setBackground(new Color(0, 153, 255));
        txtrWelcomeToGrade.setBounds(0, 119, 550, 49);
        txtrWelcomeToGrade.setFont(new Font("Corbel Light", Font.PLAIN, 46));
        txtrWelcomeToGrade.setText("    Welcome to grade saver\r\n");
        getContentPane().add(txtrWelcomeToGrade);

        JButton btnGrades = new JButton("Grades");
        btnGrades.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnGrades.setBounds(133, 452, 123, 57);
        getContentPane().add(btnGrades);

        JButton btnNotifications = new JButton("Goals");
        btnNotifications.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnNotifications.setBounds(266, 452, 123, 57);
        getContentPane().add(btnNotifications);

        JButton btnSettings = new JButton("Settings");
        btnSettings.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnSettings.setBounds(399, 452, 123, 57);
        getContentPane().add(btnSettings);
    }

    private void createMenuBar() {

        var menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        var exitIcon = new ImageIcon("src/resources/exit.png");

        var fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        var eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", exitIcon);
        eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        eMenuItem.addActionListener((event) -> System.exit(0));

        fileMenu.add(eMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            var ex = new welcomescreen();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

=================================================

## **The program that I want to go to**

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.SystemColor;

public class myschedule {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // create JFrame and JTable
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(118,129,179));
        JTable table = new JTable(); 

        // create a tnew Color(255, 255, 255)set a Column Identifiers to this model 
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        Object[] columns = {"Period 1","Period 2","Period 3","Period 4","Period 5"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);

        // set the model to the table
        table.setModel(model);

        // Change A JTable Background Color, Font Size, Font Color, Row Height
        table.setBackground(new Color(217, 240, 255));
        table.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0 ));
        Font font = new Font("",1,22);
        table.setFont(new Font("Corbel Light", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        table.setRowHeight(30);

        // create JTextFields
        JTextField textp1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textp2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textp3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textp4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField textp5 = new JTextField();
        // create JButtons
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");     


        textp1.setBounds(20, 220, 100, 25);
        textp2.setBounds(20, 250, 100, 25);
        textp3.setBounds(20, 280, 100, 25);
        textp4.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
        textp5.setBounds(20, 340, 100, 25);

        btnAdd.setBounds(150, 220, 100, 25);
        btnUpdate.setBounds(150, 265, 100, 25);
        btnDelete.setBounds(150, 310, 100, 25);

        // create JScrollPane
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(0, 0, 880, 200);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);

        // add JTextFields to the jframe
        frame.getContentPane().add(textp1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textp2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textp3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textp4);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textp5);

        // add JButtons to the jframe
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                welcomescreen home = new welcomescreen();
                home.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        btnBack.setBounds(150, 352, 100, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBack);

        // create an array of objects to set the row data
        Object[] row = new Object[5];

        // button add row
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                row[0] = textp1.getText();
                row[1] = textp2.getText();
                row[2] = textp3.getText();
                row[3] = textp4.getText();
                row[4] = textp5.getText();

                // add row to the model
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        });

        // button remove row
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    // remove a row from jtable
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Delete Error");
                }
            }
        });

        // get selected row data From table to textfields 
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

            // i = the index of the selected row
            int i = table.getSelectedRow();

            textp1.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            textp2.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            textp3.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            textp4.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
            textp5.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
        }
        });

        // button update row
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();

                if(i >= 0) 
                {
                   model.setValueAt(textp1.getText(), i, 0);
                   model.setValueAt(textp2.getText(), i, 1);
                   model.setValueAt(textp3.getText(), i, 2);
                   model.setValueAt(textp4.getText(), i, 3);
                   model.setValueAt(textp5.getText(), i, 4);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Update Error");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(890,450);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `setVisible()` on `myschedule` because that class inherits directly from `Object`, which doesn't have a `setVisible()` method. Change the class to extend `JFrame` like your other class and you can call `setVisible()`. You're going to have to change some things, however, like instantiating the `JFrame`, etc.

Also, capitalize class names. Save the lower case/camel case for instance variable names.

Comment: I am new to GUI, can you show me how to do it? I kind of didn't understand what you meant by that. Thanks

Comment: This isn't really the place to teach you the fundamentals of Java GUI development. Did you write the welcomescreen class yourself? It extends JFrame the way you should be doing with myschedule.

Comment: Oh ok, now I get it. But when I do it, the new frame is an empty one. What happened there?

Comment: Because myschedule is a full program, not just a JFrame. All you did was add "extends JFrame" to it, right? That's not enough.

Comment: So what should I do next? I am really lost right now.

Comment: Normally, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, meaning one question gets one accepted answer. Subsequent questions should be posted to separate questions, but let's see if we can get somewhere in chat. EDIT: you don't have enough rep to chat...

Comment: oh, do you use discord or anything like that?

Comment: maybe we can use different software to chat

Comment: because I still need some help with this problem

Comment: OK, the best I can do here is tell you that you have to provide getters and setters for any fields you want to be shared between the two classes. You're going to get rid of the main method from myschedule and move that stuff into an init method, just like in welcomescreen. Basically, you are combining the two classes into one. Read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Comment: I still dont understand it, can you edit my code and show me where I should make changes?

Comment: I'm super glad for you. Sorry I had to be a bit harsh, but sometimes, that's what you need to push you. You can always post more questions if you have them.